# How to write subindex with subset in greek letters

Tags: equations, subscripts, greek

I'm having a hard time to write a "a vector of parameters with subindex".

Here is what I have:

```
$\underset{\sim}{\hat{\theta}_0}$
%or
$\underset{\sim}{\hat{\theta_0}}$
%or
$\underset{\sim}{\hat{\theta}}_0$
```

[image]

But in all that cases, the resulted character was misfit/crooked.

Any hint on how can I get better result in this, how to approximate the $\sim$ to the $\theta$?

Comment: What exactly is this under tilde suppose to signify? There are other ways to do this. And what is `a vector of parameters with subindex`?

Comment: Please alway supply (short) code, which does compile when we copied and run it ...

Comment: Please don't vote to close new users' questions before they've had time to respond to comments!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do you read this out for yourself? "Theta-hat-tilde-zero", "Theta-zero-hat-tilde", ... ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not at all clear what your desired output is: so I took a guess. If it doesn't meet your requirements, please edit the question with more details.

Perhaps what you are looking for is something like

[image]

In that case you are looking for the `\underaccent` command from the [`accents`](https://ctan.org/pkg/accents?lang=en) package. The image above is made from

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}
$\underaccent{\tilde}{\hat{\theta}}_0$
\end{document}
```